# itms-services redirect using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to redirect page to any non http url?

My url is like:`itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://mydomain.com/download/iOS/myapp.plist`

I tried following code:

```
window.location.assign("itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://mydomain.com/download/iOS/myapp.plist");
```

which works in firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: Have you tried `window.location = "itms-services://?..."`?

Comment: According to MDN, it should work in Chrome: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.assign. What is `item-services`?

Comment: @FelixKling its working when we have http:// url, but here we have itms-services://

Comment: @Florent i tried but its not working

Comment: Does it work on Chrome if you use `a href` instead of `window.location`?

Comment: @Florent no its not workin in a href too

Comment: So, then I assume that  with "not working" you mean that the URL doesn't change me no redirect is happening?

Comment: @FelixKling yes you are right, not redirecting any where

Answer (score 1):

window.location.href  works fine in IOS Safari and Gmail IOS Browser.
Here is my working code:

```
<!-- Users click on this install link -->
<a href="#" onclick="trackOutboundLink('{{ download_url }}'); return false;">Install App</a>

<script>
    var trackOutboundLink = function (url) {
            // do whatever process you need here, and redirect at the end
            window.location.href = url;
        };
 </script>
```

Comment: your solution ist not working in my case, trying to setup a HTTP_Request with JS